# InfoPath Form to Populate All Site collections Users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath, rest, soap, infopath-data-connections

Actually I am working on New requirement .

I have drop down list in InfoPath form,trying to populate all site collections users in to drop down list.

When I have open Data Connection Wizard, there are two option

- SOAP Web Services
- REST web Services

[image]

I think I will get all site collections users from here.
But I don't know how to do that.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populates all site collections Users into InfoPath form Drop Down menu use Rest Web Services

The URL is
**http://sitecollection/_api/web/siteusers**

here are some screen shots 
In this screen shots you can see the I have created Data connections 
With name **ALL Users**
I have used URL required for REST  web service call

[image]

In this screen shot I have assign data connection to drop down list and select **m:properties** to display

[image]